# Frozen on Installer Boot Menu

Tags: system-installation

I am attempting to install ubuntu from a USB flash drive onto an old laptop with Windows XP. "Install Ubuntu" is highlighted in blue on the Installer boot menu and I have pressed Enter. 40 minutes later the screen still shows the Installer boot menu with Install Ubuntu highlighted and when I press any key, including escape, the computer beeps and nothing happens. What do I do now? Can anyone please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: I can post the hardware specs like RAM, CPU, graphics, available disk space, etc. Ubuntu may be too much for an "old laptop with Windows XP".