# USB installer boot menu freezes

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I booted my Acer aspire one netbook with Ubuntu USB. I created the bootable USB with universal USB installer as described in the Ubuntu site. When boot with USB disk I can see the installer boot menu. But when I try to select Install Ubuntu the menu freezes and after few seconds the key presses give me beeps. If anyone can help me with this it is appreciated.

PS: I found a duplicate of the question but no answer, [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604645/frozen-on-installer-boot-menu)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this before. The only way to make a proper ubuntu install usb is with ubuntu's built-in Startup Disk Creator - in my own experience. If you do not have that available, try making a bootable disk. Sorry if this doesn't help, but universal usb has NEVER worked with ubuntu for me.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, also with an acer one. Turns out it was the usb key. I used a different USB (also different USB port on the acer just to be safe) and the blue menu froze again, but this time only for a few seconds, then I was able to pick an option and move on!